# Multiple file uploader only sends one file

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, input

I have a multiple file input which I'm able to select multiple files but when I var_dump the file variable on the form action page there's only ever one file.

```
<input id="image" type="file" name="images" multiple="multiple">
```

Here's the dump `var_dump($_FILES);`

```
array(1) { ["images"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_4511.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(26) "/private/var/tmp/php8g7CV3" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(730250) } }
```

Here's the opening form tag:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="http://localhost.com/item/update" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<input id="image" type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Should work

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't think I needed to add the []. Even though it was only one file in the var_dump it was still an array. but yeah adding [] showed the extra images. Cheers

Comment: without the [], it just makes it a single variable that gets passed. When you add the [] and post it to php, it's saying more than one of this field.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your input `name` is an array if you are accepting multiple files:

Single upload:
`<input name="productImage" accept="image/*" type="file" />`

Multiple uploads:
`<input name="productImage[]" accept="image/*" type="file" />`
`<input name="productImage[]" accept="image/*" type="file" />`
...
--------------------------------------^ The `[]` signifies this is an array and allows you to submit multiple values for the same name.

Then you will find multiple values for `$_FILES` instead of only the last file uploaded (as each file is basically overriding the last currently)